# MaterialPage not found inside a list of pages inside a Navigator

Tags: amazon-web-services, flutter, aws-amplify

I am trying to achieve a [course in AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/build-flutter-app-amplify/module-one/) to connect Amplify in Flutter. But inside 'Create Authentication Flow', when it adds `MaterialPage` inside a `pages`, inside `Navigator` it doesn't found.
I have this error in the `MaterialPage`:

> The method 'MaterialPage' isn't defined for the type '_MyAuthStateState'.  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'MaterialPage'.

My current code (main.dart):

```flutter
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final _authService = AuthService();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _authService.showLogin();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Photo Gallery App',
      theme: ThemeData(visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity),
      home: StreamBuilder<AuthState>(
          // 2
          stream: _authService.authStateController.stream,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            // 3
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return Navigator(
                pages: [
                  // 4
                  // Show Login Page
                  if (snapshot.data.authFlowStatus == AuthFlowStatus.login)
                    MaterialPage(
                      child: LoginPage(
                        shouldShowSignUp: _authService.showSignUp,
                        didProvideCredentials:
                            _authService.loginWithCredentials,
                      ),
                    ),
                  // 5
                  // Show Sign Up Page
                  if (snapshot.data.authFlowStatus == AuthFlowStatus.signUp)
                    MaterialPage(
                        child: SignUpPage(
                      shouldShowLogin: _authService.showLogin,
                      didProvideCredentials: _authService.signUpWithCredentials,
                    )),
                  if (snapshot.data.authFlowStatus ==
                      AuthFlowStatus.verification)
                    MaterialPage(
                        child: VerificationPage(
                            didProvideVerificationCode:
                                _authService.verifyCode))
                ],
                onPopPage: (route, result) => route.didPop(result),
              );
            } else {
              // 6
              return Container(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            }
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing your `_authService.showLogin()` inside `initState` is trying to perform some navigation, i.e. showing a Widget.  Since MyApp doesn't connect itself to the top level Navigator automatically, you can't access/use Navigator functionality.

A MaterialApp will hook you up the top-level Navigator for you automatically.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // ↓ Make MaterialApp your root widget
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Photo Gallery App',
      theme: ThemeData(visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity),
      home: MyAuthStatePage(),
    )
  }
}

class MyAuthStatePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => MyAuthState();
}

class MyAuthState extends State<MyAuthStatePage> {
  final _authService = AuthService();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    _authService.showLogin();
  }
}
```

Also, initState prob. isn't the right place to be navigating/showing widgets, rather it's there for preparing state that'll be used by widgets inside the build method.

Comment: Still have the same error... `The method 'MaterialPage' isn't defined for the type '_MyAuthStateState'.  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'MaterialPage'.`

Comment: And you have `import 'package:flutter/material.dart';` at the top of your file?

Comment: Yes, is at the top of the file